# Disabling multiple ratings in Tridion UGC

Tags: tridion

I've got a prototype UGC project running but the issue of multiple ratings has been raised today.  Currently the user is able to enter multiple ratings which would skew the ratings.  Ideally we'd like to restrict this to allow a user to rate an item once and then if they changed their rating then only their rating would change.  How do we achieve this?  Is it through UGC configuration?  Is it through a spam configuration?

Thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the Tridion Installation Manual? Chapter 9 details the installation of UGC and section 9.6.4 talks about the management of visitor accounts.

You will need to utilise user management in order to store which users have entered which ratings/comments. This can be done with anonymous users using cookies to store anonymous user ids.

There are sample pages included in the Tridion installation media which give examples of using the following approaches for user management including:

- Standalone (using UGC itself to manage accounts)
- Using Audience Manager for storing user accounts
- Integrating to external systems

The documentation also includes examples for the code that would be required for Audience Manager integration.

Mike

Comment: I've had more time to look into the documentation and the sample and I'm not sure it's as useful as I'd have hoped for you. It seems to deal more with comments (you're obviously dealing with ratings) and the examples seem to be heavily focused on integration with Audience Manager.
It does mention that:
"For a variety of reasons, you may want to identify the Web site visitors who submit comments or ratings:
 - To prevent a visitor from rating an item more than once"

and "Anonymous users can still be identified through cookies" but no explanation of how is included so this is no use!

Comment: Thanks Mike.  As you say, the examples don't really deal with ratings.  If I find anything in the meantime I'll feed back.